# Nodered: can't send data from frontend to backend using eventlistener

Tags: node.js, node-red

I have created a custom node for the nodered editor and am trying to listen to an emitter from the frontend.
However, the listener only seems to work for events from the backend.
Switch it around and it seems to work. The frontend listener receives the data I am trying to send.

Is it perhaps not possible to listen for events coming from the frontend?

The backend looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
    function TestingNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
        let node = this;

        //Listener works fine, if the emitter is also in the backend
        RED.events.on("runtime-event", function(event) {
            if (event.id === 'mySuperCreativeId') {
                // Emit the event to the node's output
                node.send({ payload: event.payload });
                node.warn("works fine");
            }
        });

        //Emitter works for backend and frontend
        node.on('input', function(msg) {
            RED.events.emit("runtime-event", {
                id: 'mySuperCreativeId',
                retain: false,
                payload: "some payload"
            });
        });
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("testingNode", TestingNode);
};
```

The frontend like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

    //this listener works fine
    RED.comms.subscribe("notification/#", function (topic, payload) {
        if (topic.startsWith("notification/mySuperCreativeId")) {
            alert(payload);
        }
    });

    RED.nodes.registerType('testingNode',{
        category: 'function',
        color: '#e2d96e',
        defaults: {
            name: {value:""}
        },
        inputs:1,
        outputs:1,
        icon: "white-globe.png",
        label: function() {
            return this.name||"testingNode";
        }
    });

    
    function start() {
        // nothing seems to happen here
        RED.events.emit("runtime-event", {
            id: 'mySuperCreativeId',
            retain: false,
            payload: "some payload"
        });
    }

    RED.sidebar.addTab({
        id: "123456789",
        label: "Testing",
        name: "Testing",
        iconClass: "fa fa-tasks",
        content:'<button onclick="start()">start</button></div>'   
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work this way, the frontend/backend code are totally separate.

If you want to send events from the editor to the backend, you need to implement a HTTP endpoint in the backend code, and make a HTTP call in the frontend.

There a multiple examples of this pattern in the core nodes e.g. the inject node

https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/packages/node_modules/%40node-red/nodes/core/common/20-inject.js